# Create node from JSON

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm looking to write the following module, any help, guidance, and advice would be greatly appreciated.

- User is logged into site.
- Site has two content types: page & note.
- Logged in user can create content type note only.
- User is viewing a node: /node/5.
- User selects some text in the body.
- Link/icon is shown above selected text.
- User clicks clicks and is taken to /node/add/note
- Some fields are pre-populated on Node edit page, including:

  - title, field_source_quote, field_entity_reference_nid
- User adds his "note" to field_user_note and saves note

From my basic understanding of JSON, I should be able to create a JSON of the user selected text with something like:

```
var selectedText = "";
selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();

var noteData={
    "sourcePath": "/node/being/viewed",
    "selectedText": selectedText
};
```

How do I get noteData to a module? Better yet, how do I get nodeData to the node/add/note page and pre-populate the correct fields?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

======= Updates Below =============

**Passing data through local storage (Andrew's Approach)**

I can confirm this approach is viable. There are a number of issues, however that this presents:

1. I'm sure this is not the most "drupal-ized" way to perform this.
2. If the node admin pages use a different theme, the js to retrieve and apply the data must be within the other them.
3. Need to have a persistent marker placed for the user ui (i.e. highlighting the text they have added a "note" to).

I've come across a library that might be helpful for #3: Rangy (https://github.com/timdown/rangy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little working piece of code for you. You may extend it according to your needs

```
document.onselectionchange = function() {
    var selectedText = "";
    $('div').mouseup(function() {
      //Save selected text in localStorage.
      selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
      if (selectedText.length > 10) {
        var noteData={
          "sourcePath": window.location.href,
          "selectedText": selectedText
        };
        localStorage.setItem('noteData', JSON.stringify(noteData));
        window.location.href = '/node/add/page';
      }
    });
  };

  // Get saved data from localStorage and insert in the form.
  var savedNoteData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('noteData'));
  if (savedNoteData && savedNoteData.selectedText) {
    $('.form-item-title input').val(savedNoteData.selectedText);
    localStorage.setItem('noteData', '');
  }
```

Comment: Interesting, so you're saying that I can pass/retrieve noteData via localStorage... I never thought of that - I will give that a shot and report back.

Comment: I've updated the post to reflect your idea. I'll give another couple of weeks to see if any one else has any options.